# Jump the current time of video player onclick of a row of table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I am working on a reactjs application. I am using videojs in it. I have a table on the samme page where videojs is there. each row has a time column.

**Desired Output**: When I click on any row, video js currentTime should get set to the corresponding time of that row's column

**What I tried:** I used redux. When I click on any row, I dispatch an action.

```
 <tr onClick={()=>this.sentance_click(item.time)}>

sentance_click(time){
        console.log("clicked with time " + time)
        this.props.sentanceSelectedAction(time)


    }
```

sentanceClickAction is

```
export const sentanceSelectedAction= (time) => {
    return {
        type: 'SENTANCE_CLICKED',
        time: time
    }
};
```

This action is listened by a reducer. The reducer has a variable called flag. It's initialized value is false. Now whenever I click on the row, it dispatches the action and sets the flag variable in reducer to true.

```
const initialState ={
    sentanceTime:0,
    flag:false
}
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SENTANCE_CLICKED' :
            state = {...state, sentanceTime: action.time, flag:true}
    }
    return state;
}
```

Now in my Video Component I check for this flag and if that is true then call a method which sets the currentTime of player to that row's time. But I am checking that flag in my render method

```
render() {

        if (this.props.sentance_selected_reducer.flag) {
            // this.jumpToSpecificMarker();
            // this.state.player.pause();
            this.skipTime
        }
```

and skip time function is outside the render method

```
skipTime(){
        console.log("inside skip")
        player.currentTime(10)

    }
```

player variable is declared outside of class. And this how I initialize my videojs

```
componentDidMount = ()=> {
        this.init()
    }


    init = ()=> {
        this.initVideoJS()
    }


    initVideoJS = ()=> {
        var self = this;
        var that = this;
        debug('Init VideoJS')
        const options = {
            fluid: true,
            preload: false,
            autoplay: false,
            controls: true,
            aspectRatio: "16:9"
        }

        this.video = player = videojs(this.video_el, options).ready(function () {
            self.player = this;
            self.player.on('play', that.handlePlay);
        });
```

**Result: I get an error saying cannot read property "currentTime" of undefined**

Comment: Are you sure that `player` is defined in `skipTime`? Try printing it out in the previous `console.log`.

Comment: player is not defined in skip time. It is defined outside the class. Mostly the problem lies in calling skipTime from render.

Comment: Can you just set `player` (not sure where this is defined) to the value of `self.player` in `initVideoJs`?

Comment: @mrmcgreg I tried. Same error.